# ACF acf_register_form() - One form create page and product

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I need to create a product and a page with one form.

```
$new_product = [
  "post_type" => "product",
  "post_status" => "draft",
];

$new_events = [
  "post_type" => "events",
  "post_status" => "draft",
];

acf_register_form([
    "id" => "new-events",
    "post_id" => "new_post",
    "new_post" => $new_events and $new_product,
    "post_title" => true,
    "uploader" => "basic",
    'updated_message' => __("Wydarzenie zostało dodane.", 'acf'),
    "fields" => $fields,
    "submit_value" => "Dodaj wydarzenie",
]);
```

I am trying to do it as in the example above.

Comment: bump bump bump bump